# reinstalling dropbox.exe but leaving files on that system intact

Tags: dropbox

For some reason (I do not know why), dropbox.exe disappeared from my tray and I couldn't find it my windows program menu either.  It showed that it was installed when I went to control panel>remove programs.  So I unistalled db then reinstalled it.  When I restarted db, however, it looked like it wasn't aware of the selective sync configuration on that machine.  It may be that I didn't give db time to figure it out, but I quickly paused syncing, set selective sync to the way it was prior to reinstall of db.

Then I had a sinking (syncing) feeling that maybe dropbox wasn't smart enough to realize it already had these 10,000 or so files on this machine already in the cloud and would create 10,000 conflicted copies---not something I wanted.  So I wrote db help, but really got no comforting answer.  The person didn't seem to grasp my question and gave me answers that left me wondering.

So I'm still paused on that machine.  Hoping that I can gain some clarity.  I'd rather disconnect the machine from the dropbox ecosystem, delete all the files and start over again--as if it were a new machine--rather than deal with 10,000 superfluous conflicted copies.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what question you'd like answered? Are you asking  if its possible to make DB recognize the selective sync settings and download only the non-redundant files? Are you asking for advice on the most efficient way to re-sync?

Comment: I want dropbox to respect the files that remained, update them in the event they've been changed by another source during the period this machine was off line, and only create conflicted copies in the case where a true conflict (i.e. two files of the same name in the same location with different contents) exists. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the question you ask and their response?

Answer (score 0):

When the Dropbox desktop application is installed, it doesn't create a folder in the Program Files location as most applications do; it installs as a User-specific program by default. I assume that this is so that only the user who installed it will have access to his/her files. This is why it did not appear in your program files/start menu.

I just stumbled across a troubleshooting feature that you may want to try: While logged into the web UI, if you go to a Dropbox help page such as [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/321), you may see a message across the top that says "You recently deleted, moved, or renamed more than ### files from your account. Do you need help restoring them?" If you see that message, click "Yes" and see if it can help you:

[image]

If that doesn't work for you, I think you ought to move the local files you have to another location, either on an external storage device or at least to a folder that Dropbox won't try to access. It sounds like you have a ton of data so, if this is not feasible, just log onto the web UI and make sure that everything is there and up to date. Once you are sure that Dropbox still has all of your files, re-install and let it re-sync everything to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem, the Dropbox.exe disappeared for no reason from my Dropbox\bin directory. The solution that worked for me was to [install DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/install) again with out uninstalling it. That way it kept all the previous configurations and files, and only added Dropbox.exe to the Dropbox\bin directory.